# Tokenization with Firebase Phone Auth and React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

**My experience level:** I am newbie to both Firebase and React-Native.

**Context:** I am working on a mobile app, and trying to implement Phone Auth. Firebase built-in SMS service is not working as consistent as I wanted it to be. So replaced SMS / OTP part with an external messaging provider.  Currently when a user enters their phone number on login screen, receives an OTP, and upon entering OTP the app verifies and let the user in. All fine so far.

**Problem:**
What I dont understand is, how to get a session token from Firebase (especially, when I am using an external SMS service) and persist it in AsyncStorage. So to protect the entire app

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export  async function setUserToken(user:any) {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("userLoggedIn", true);        
     } catch (error) {
       console.log("Something went wrong", error);
   }
```

**NOTE:** Dont have a backend server or anything to implement JWT auth myself

Comment: Firebase-admin gives you feature to implement custom token, you can use that to create custom JWT tokens.

Comment: Ok thanks @navneet let me take a look!